# sending an image to an URL in android

Tags: android, url, camera

the following is the code which i am using to capture an image from the camera in my app

```
   public void startCamera() 
    {
        Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
        String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

after capturing the image and when i select insert it gets stored in memory but i want it to be sent to an URL and i want it to be viewed in another activity.

how to do this pls help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the URL of the image.

```
  public void startCamera(){
   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);  
  }

   Uri selectedImageUri;
   private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) { 
            selectedImageUri = Intent.getData();                        

        }
```

You will be getting the URI in `SelectedImageURI`, then you can send that using `Intent.putExtra();`

This works for me.

Comment: Captured image in the sense it is available in the Gallery right? or do u need to capture n have to send?

Comment: in case if u want to select from the gallery then use this..       `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

Comment: Then u check with the `requestCode == 1` in `OnActivityResult`